# Broadcasting with Pusher fails with TOKEN_INVALID unless I fully refresh the page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm trying to broadcast events with Laravel Echo (with Vue). This is my setup:

**BroadcastServiceProvider**

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

**Echo config**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: '...',
  cluster: 'eu',
  encrypted: true,
  namespace: 'App.Events',
  authEndpoint: `${window.location.origin}/broadcasting/auth`,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('quiz-token')}`
    }
  }
})
```

**Main Vue component where broadcasting should happen**

```
  mounted () {
    this.gameKey = 'game.' + this.$route.params.id

    Echo.join(this.gameKey)
      .here((users) => {
        console.warn(users.length + ' online in game ' + this.gameKey)
      })
  }
```

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('game.{gameId}', function ($user, $gameId) {
    // Auth validation here
});
```

Now, the problem is whenever I launch the game, I get this **401 TOKEN_INVALID** error:

[image: Error]
However, if I refresh the page manually (F5), I am suddenly connected to Pusher and everything is working fine.

I suspect this is indeed related to tokens being invalid but I have no clue why - I am testing in an incognito window, so theoretically logging in for the first time, which would mean the tokens are brand new.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is LocalStorage `quiz-token` being set?

Comment: It's being set by VueAuth (uses jwt-auth).

Comment: Am not familiar with Vue, but I suspect `quiz-token` is being set after the pusher instance has been initiated. Try initiating pusher once auth has completed.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't things fail every time? When I hard refresh the quiz page, everything works as expected so I don't think it's an order issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be authenticated and if you are the channel you are listening to is not allowed for logged user. If you are authenticated check your **channels.php** file to return true if ids are same

Comment: I am authenticated - otherwise I wouldn't be able to access any page (JWT middleware). The thing is everything works fine if I refresh the page, otherwise it's just the broadcasting that fails. Every route, access credential etc. works well.

Comment: Then I really think that you should return something from inside Broadcast::channel. Try returning raw true see if that fixes the problem, then work from there onwards

Comment: I am returning my validation conditions (just didn't add those to the snippet above). Even with return true; the same thing happens: 401 if I'm coming from the dashboard into the quiz; but if I refresh the page directly in the quiz everything works with Pusher.